# How to implement cache system in php for json api

Tags: php, json, api, caching, curl

I have a few custom social buttons on my website for whom I get the share number/followers number using json from API.
I have tried to implement a cache system to reduce the load time and eliminate de risk of being 'red-flagged' for over-using the APIs. However, I had no success in this area, basically because I don't quite understand the integration steps.
I hope someone could help me integrate a cache system.

Here are the php codes for Twitter, Google Plus and Instagram:

- Twitter

```
    ob_start();
    $twittershare = 'http://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url='.$product["href"] .'';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $twittershare);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $jsonstring = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $bufferstr = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $json = json_decode($bufferstr);

    echo $json->count;
```

- Google Plus

```
    $url = ''.$product["href"] .'';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=xxxxxxxxxx");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '[{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"' . $url . '","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}]');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $curl_results = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $json = json_decode($curl_results, true);
    $count = intval($json[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count']);
    $data = array();
    $data['plus_count'] = (string) $count;
    $data['url'] = $url;
    echo $data['plus_count'];
```

- Instagram (fetching followers number)

```
    ob_start();
    $insta = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/00000000?access_token={token}';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $insta);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $jsonstring = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $bufferstr = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $json = json_decode($bufferstr);

    echo $json->data->counts->followed_by;
```

Hope you guys can guide me step by step as to how to implement a cache system for the code snippets above.

Comment: You mention "eliminate de risk of being 'red-flagged' for over-using the APIs" and I ask myself: what are those limits? Does your site get that many requests? As for the caching system: it depends: you could store the result of your requests in a database or memcached with a timestamp and only update them as needed (by a distinct service e.g. via a cron job). Your page merely reads from the data backend and fetches it if it's not available.

Comment: @nietonfir I honestly do not know the limits, but the main issue is long page loading time. Yes, i've read about it, I just have no clue how to actually implement it. Wouldn't it be easier and less stresful for the database to store the result in a file on the server? Again, I am merely guessing from what I've read here and there.

Comment: No, you don't want to store anything in a file. If page loading time is your main concern, then don't fetch the data from the APIs (or your caching system) during the request but asyncronously (via AJAX). This would also allow you to implement the caching system independently.

Answer (score 6):

Well, as mentioned in my comment, I'd use [Memcached](http://www.memcached.org/) and a database, but I'll draft a database-only solution (with PDO for twitter) and leave the Memcached part as bonus exercise for you. ;)
I would load the follower information via AJAX to reduce page loading time for when e.g. the follower count needs to be updated.

I'll be using the following database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Followers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `data` longtext NOT NULL,
  `followers` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `last_update` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

First I'd define an interface so you don't rely on any implementations:

```
interface SocialFollowers
{
    public function getFollowers();
}
```

Then, for the twitter share API I'd have an implementing class that gets a database handle and the target URL for initialization. The class attributes are populated with the retrieved data (if available). If the timestamp is new enough you'll get the amount of followers instantly, else the API is queried, the results stored and then the amount of followers retrieved.

```
class TwitterFollowers implements SocialFollowers
{
    private $data = null;
    private $url = "";
    private $db = null;
    private $followers = null;

    protected $shareURL = "https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=";

    public function __construct($db, $url) {
        // initialize the database connection here
        // or use an existing handle
        $this->db = $db;

        // store the url
        $this->url = $url;

        // fetch the record from the database
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `Followers` WHERE url = :url ORDER BY last_update DESC LIMIT 1');
        $stmt->bindParam(":url", $url);
        $stmt->execute();

        $this->data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if (!empty($this->data))
            $this->followers = $this->data["followers"];
    }

    public function getFollowers()
    {
        // create a timestamp that's 30 minutes ago
        // if it's newer than the value from the database -> call the api
        $old = new DateTime();
        $old->sub(new DateInterval("PT30M"));

        if (is_null($this->followers) || (new DateTime($this->data["last_update"]) < $old) ) {
            return $this->retrieveFromAPI();
        }

        return $this->followers;
    }

    private function retrieveFromAPI()
    {
        // mostly untouched
        ob_start();
        $twittershare = $this->shareURL . $this->url;

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $twittershare);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        $jsonstring = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $bufferstr = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $json = json_decode($bufferstr);

        $this->followers = $json->count;

        // store the retrieved values in the database
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO Followers (url, data, followers)'
            .'VALUES (:url, :data, :followers)');
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ":url" => $this->url,
            ":data" => $bufferstr,
            ":followers" => $this->followers
        ));

        return $this->followers;
    }
}
```

For Facebook, Google+, the-next-social-network you just need to add another implementation.

Please keep in mind that this code isn't tested. It misses some try/catch blocks for the PDO queries and there's room for improvement (e.g.: some kind of locking mechanism is missing to prevent the concurrent retrieval of the same URL, is it necessary to store the returned blob, etc.).

Hope this helps you.

[edit] I updated the code slightly (fixed some typos and conversion issues) and tested it. You can find a working version at [github](https://github.com/nietonfir/cache_example_php). All that's missing is the ajax snippet (assuming jQuery) like

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/twitter.php",
    type: "get",
    data: {url: "http://stackoverflow.com"}
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // Update the corresponding counter like
        // $("#twitterfollowers").text(data);
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @nietonfir for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work, it breaks the page. I don't know, I just don't feel comfortable messing with the database, it's the main core for storing important information of my website.

Comment: @CristiSilaghi I don't know how you come to the conclusion "messing with the database" because a database is for storing data. ;-) Simply use another database/table if you don't want to keep that information in the same storage layer as your website. And as I said, the code's not tested or complete (e.g. the AJAX calls are missing) but should give you an idea.

Comment: you're right, I haven't thought about using a separate database. How silly of me :) I don't know this kind of php coding(at this high level), so an incomplete code doesn't really help me. That's why I posted this question, to get help in implementing. I found several tutorials on the internet, but I am quite the php newbie in the cache section.

Comment: @CristiSilaghi I updated the answer and fixed the code example. I hope the working code gives you enough information to get you going. Good luck.

Comment: if you're worried about messing with the database, just make a little SQLite `database` instead. a SQLite db is just a file, fopen() style, that will be completely independent on your existing db

Comment: @nietonfir btw, make a habit of using $stmt->bindValue instead of $stmt->bindParam when `it doesn't really matter` - references (that bindParam makes) will try try to bite you in the ass if you're not very careful with what you put into that variable later, bindValue doesn't do that.

Comment: You could also use php session array for this. No need sql or memcached and it's faster.

Comment: @MaXi32 You can, but that would undermine the whole concept of caching in the first place, since a session is bound to the user-agent with the corresponding session key. And the session-handler is files by default, so a database connection/redis/memcached/… will most certainly be faster.

Comment: @nietonfir I will test this solution u have given. seems like a good idea. thanks a lot